# How to detect Ctrl - Forward Slash in WinForm app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

Below is the code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (from another SO post). But how do you detect a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ForwardSlash</kbd>? or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (note: divide does not work)

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (1 == 1) //keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("What the Ctrl+F?");
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: The Control modifier makes it want Question instead of Divide - at least on US keyboards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Divide should work fine.

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>:

```
if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.OemPipe) )
```

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>:

```
if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.OemQuestion) )
```

For some reason (not sure why), when you trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + these keys, they're mapping to the "shifted" keymappings.

---

Edit:

One trick for finding this, or any other key.  Set a breakpoint on any line in that method, and look at the `keyData` value when you press the key you're trying to trap.  I recommend doing this without hitting control.  You can then use reflector to get all of the specific values for `Keys`, and find the "key" with the appropriate value.

Comment: didn't work for me. note: I'm talking about the / above enter or near it. Not on the numeric keypad (if you are on laptop). Any simple way to capture actual key codes in a messagebox and then just rewrite using numeric codes?

Comment: @Tyndall: I just tested this.  My new answer will give you the correct response.

Comment: On my keyboard, the backslash is above enter.

Comment: @recursive. It is on mine too.

Comment: sorry I meant / below and to the left of enter on the ? key. Wonder, why the / maps to shifted with the Ctrl pressed. Seems like a bug. I play around with this more. May just have the users use F12, if I can't make this reliable across my corp's desktops and laptops (7 or 8 models)

Comment: This is quite an old post, but for posterity, I found a detailed explanation of different key capture approaches on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459067/winforms-capturing-the-combination-of-key-presses-using-processcmdkey-vs-keydo)