# Key Down with Dollar

Tags: c#, keydown

I'm use this code for block the dollar button shift+4 = $.
On this table http://expandinghead.net/keycode.html the $ is code 36

now the code on keydown:

```
if (e.KeyValue == 36)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

code not work why?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459067/winforms-capturing-the-combination-of-key-presses-using-processcmdkey-vs-keydo

Comment: 2000 line for one key?? No thanks!

Comment: This might not be an issue in your application, but be aware that if a user uses a different keyboard layout or if he copy-pastes a `$` from somewhere else he might bypass your validation.

Comment: it's all about the keypreview property -_-

Comment: Never use KeyDown for typing keys, different keyboard layouts have different captions.  Lots of cultures have layouts that don't have the $ at all, that's not the currency they use.  Also the flaw in your code, you won't suppress NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol for those users.  The proper way to do this is to use the Validating event and format the entered value as a decimal without the currency symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you first press `shift` and then 4, so you will get the code of `shift` (key value 16) separately when using `KeyDown` event.

To achieve what you want, use `KeyPress` event, not `KeyDown`. `KeyPress` will register the character you typed (`$`), not individual keys pressed.

```
if (e.KeyChar == '$')
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: if (e.KeyData == Keys.Shift && e.KeyData == Keys.D4)
                e.Handled = true; not work

Comment: same problem with this code if (e.KeyValue == 36 && e.KeyValue == 16)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

Comment: @Federal09: That makes no sense. `KeyData` or `KeyValue` can't have two different values at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Why not on KeyPress event

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '$')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd use for specific chars (I'd use KeyDown for special keys such as PgDn or anything else which doesn't have a corresponding char)