# WinForms ListBox intermittently changes the selection on CTRL+ENTER

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I'm adding hotkey support to an app, and throughout, I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> as the hotkey for confirming dialogs.

I'm having a unique issue in the dialog below, which contains a `ListBox`.  If the `ListBox` has the focus (it usually does) when the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> hotkey is pressed, it *intermittently* shifts the `ListBox` selection down one position.

This creates a problem, since changing the selected item in the `ListBox` updates the **New Customer Name** field.  What's happening is users choose the settings they want, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to execute the merge, and the settings suddenly change just before the merge occurs.

I'm not handling any key events on the ListBox, and the selection change is weirdly intermittent (perhaps 1 in 8 times).  I also can't seem to get <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to cause selection changes intentionally.

What causes this behavior, and how do I suppress it?

[image]

### Hotkey Handling

The approach I'm using to Form-level hotkey handling is to set `Form.KeyPreview = true` and to handle the `KeyUp` event.  Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459159/1849956), this is the cleanest way to support the handling of modifier keys, and it seems to work like a charm.

```
    private void frmMerge_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Escape:    

                Close(); // Close Form 

                return;
            case Keys.Enter:

                if (e.Control) // CTRL+ENTER  
                    ActionMerge(); // Merge Customer 

                return;
        }
    }
```

### ListBox Use

The ListBox is setup very simply. It is populated once on Form Load;

```
    private void frmMerge_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Add all Customers to the list 
        foreach(Customer customer in Customers)
        {
            lbxNames.Items.Add(customer.Name); 
        }

        // If there are items, select the first one 
        if (lbxNames.Items.Count > 0)
            lbxNames.SelectedIndex = 0; 

    }
```

And it handles one event, `SelectedIndexChanged`, to update the New Customer Name `TextBox`

```
    private void lbxNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtName.Text = lbxNames.SelectedItem as string; 
    }
```

These are the only two places that the ListBox is touched in code.

Comment: could you please post some code to make your problem reproducible ?

Comment: Thanks @Mong, done.  There isn't any other code that relates to key handling, or ListBox events.

Comment: what happens in `ActionMerge` ? any access to the listbox?

Comment: @MongZhu  No, none at all.  The list box is set up very simply.  It's populated on form load, and it has a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler which updates the New Customer Name textbox.. I've added that code to my question.

Comment: sorry dude, unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks @MongZhu, I'm continuing to explore the problem.  I've discovered that the intermittency is actually connected to using the CTRL+M hotkey to open the Merge dialog.  For some reason that 'M' seems to stick in a key queue somewhere, perhaps in the keyboard buffer or driver?  On executing the CTRL+ENTER hotkey, that M fires as well.  In the ListBox, pressing M only shifts the selected record if there is a record beginning with 'M'.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to the problem, but not determined the cause.  My best guess is that I'm dealing with a keyboard hardware or driver issue, rather than a `ListBox` issue.

The intermittent nature of the problem was caused by the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> hotkey combination, which is used to open my Merge dialog.  That <kbd>M</kbd> appears to stick in a key queue somewhere, perhaps in the hardware keyboard buffer or driver.  On executing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> hotkey, that <kbd>M</kbd> fires a second time. In the `ListBox`, pressing <kbd>M</kbd> only shifts the selected record if there is a record beginning with `M`.

### Workaround

I made two changes.  First I suppress the <kbd>M</kbd> key in the `ListBox`.  This works fine for me, since I only need arrow key and home/end navigation in the `ListBox`, and not alphabetic selection.

```
    private void lbxNames_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Suppress listbox hotkeys to prevent dialog hotkey conflicts
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.M:
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // required
                break;
        }
    }
```

Second, I changed my dialog-level hotkeys handler to use the `ProcessCmdKey` approach in place of `KeyUp`.  The reason for this is that using `KeyUp` event handlers conflicted strangely between the `Form` level and the `ListBox` level.  Many keys would get captured by the `ListBox` first, even with `KeyPreview` enabled.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {

        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Escape:
                // Close the dialog
                Close();
                return true;
            case Keys.Control | Keys.Enter:
                // Perform the primary action
                ActionMerge();
                return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```